# Wordpress Opt-In Form with Social Login to receive Leads from Users

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I am an Online Marketer and I am facing a problem: People are not converting when visiting my page through a smartphone. My interpretation is: they are lazy, as I am too.

I am not too terrible deep into programming Wordpress, but I thought about something and seeking advise:

1. I want to to build a Opt-In Form, which uses Facebooks "Social Login"
   to process the Lead.
2. I need to find a way to get the "E-Mail-Adress" through the Facebook open graph API.
3. I generated a lead with one simple click.

I guess Online Marketers are graving for a feature like this!

So my question is:

**Do you think it is possible to build a Wordpress Opt-In Form which uses Social Login (Facebook, Google) to receive E-Mail-Adresses from my users?**

Maybe someone has some experience with this.

Best wishes
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to capture user's email address from facebook without permission of that user. However, there are a number of plugins that show popups and widgets to get users to subscribe to your newsletter etc.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/optin-forms/screenshots/

Also, if your content is good and if you create a catchy Call to Action, then it's possible to get more people to subscribe to your blog.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Of course I want to get the permission.

Comment: I got catchy CTAs and they convert, but not on smartphones ;)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the process of opting into a subscription more involved than simply entering a name and email? Personally, I will ignore an optin form that requires me to do a social login.

Using a regular [WordPress opt-in form](https://mailoptin.io) [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailoptin/) would suffice.

By the way, do you have any data that shows conversion is low because social login isn't present?